# connectionString Can not be null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with the connection string that sits inside the json configuration file , 
as usual :

1. i have created a class : applicationDbcontext
2. i made a DbSet {get;set;}
3. integrate it into the controller
4. add it to the services

I have read and try all the advices inserted in the related question :
[asp.net core 2.0 - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010003/asp-net-core-2-0-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-connectionstring)
But none of them works with me 
 Here is my implementation , 
I hope someone can help me , thank you

A_ DB Context :

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

B_ App Settings :config.json and config.development.json

```
{
    "ConnectionString": {
        "testConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=mvc_db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"

}
```

C_ Services Injection

Startup  :

```
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.Json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

Configuration Services :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("testConnection"));
            });
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```

D_ Injection Into Controllers :

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public PersonController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            People = _db.Persons.ToList();
            return View(People);
        }
```

I have tried to insert the whole connectionString inside the configuration.GetConnectionString("Here");
And To change the location of the connection string from up to down and vice verse.
But nothing fix the return null value  problem of the connectionString .
Any Help please Thanks[image]

Comment: The default set-up provided include the type when declaring the parameters in the ApplicationDBContext constructor

        
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

Not sure it would change much, but something i noticed that was different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this structure for the connectionString

```
 {

 "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "xxx"
   }
}
```

Check the json file you missed the `s` it should be `ConnectionStrings`

And Access Your Connection String in this simple way

```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

In your case `DefaultConnection` should be `testConnection`

Comment: Good spot on the property name but the name of the connection string does not have to be `DefaultConnection`.

Comment: excellent my friend the connectionString should be plural ... but the name can be what ever you want

Comment: Hello. In which file is the "ConnectionStrings": { written?

Comment: @ValterEkholm in appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to insert the whole connectionString inside the
>   configuration.GetConnectionString("Here");

But did you try changing:

```
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("testConnection"));
```

to

```
options.UseSqlServer("your connection string");
```

Also, you mentioned you have `config.json` and `config.development.json`, but they should be `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.development.json`